# Trouble with WPF ComboBox and selected item

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having the darnedest time getting a ComboBox to work. The XAML below...

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem>ComboBox Item #1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>ComboBox Item #2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>ComboBox Item #3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

with the C# code behind...

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, selectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string val = comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

The value of val will be...

> System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: ComboBox Item #2

Where is the "System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: " coming from and how do i get rid of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`SelectedValue` in this case will return a `ComboBoxItem`.  What you are seeing is the result of calling `ToString` on that.

If you just want the *content* of that `ComboBoxItem`, you need to access it:

```
var item = (ComboBoxItem)comboBox.SelectedValue;
var content = (string)item.Content;
```

Alternatively, set `SelectedValuePath="Content"` (in the XAML) and then `SelectedValue` will simply return the content string.

Comment: Thanks! I do like the Alternate method better.

Answer (score 1):

so the combo box has a collection of type combo box item.  so when you select an item the selected item dependency property becomes a specific instance of type combo box item.  The `ToString()` method is called on the combo box item, resulting in the output of:

> System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: ComboBox Item #2

to get the value of the combo box item, you can try to call the `Content` property of your item.  Keep in mind though that the content can be anything.  One common practice is to bind your combo box to a collection (typically `ObservableCollection<T>`) and your selected item is of type `T`.  From there you can get specific properties out of your object. An example of this would be similar to the following

C#

```
public class MyType
{
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public string Text {get; set;}
}

//CodeBehind
public class CodeBehindClass
{
  public ObservableCollection<MyType> MyCollection {get; set;} = new ObservableCollection();

  public MyType SelectedItem {get; set;}

  //Populate collection

  MyComboBox.ItemsSource = MyCollection;

  private void MyComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, selectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    SelectedItem = (MyType)MyComboBox.SelectedValue;
    //display string with SelectedItem.Text;
  }
}
```

XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox" SelectionChanged="MyComboBox_SelectionChanged" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: ComboBox Item #2

is coming from the `SelectedValue` because it returns the entire object not just the string.
you can try `GetItemText` instead i modified your code behind to suite your requirement:

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, selectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.ComboBox.GetItemText(this.Combobox.SelectedItem);
}
```

Comment: `SelectedItem` *definitely* returns the object.  You can change what `SelectedValue` returns by changing the `SelectedValuePath`.

Comment: yeah after i try it i found it is the same now i edited the answer :) hope it will work for you